# how to exclude null values in array_agg like in string_agg using postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-8.4

If I use `array_agg` to collect names, I get my names separated by commas, but in case there is a `null` value, that null is also taken as a name in the aggregate. For example :

```
SELECT g.id,
       array_agg(CASE WHEN g.canonical = 'Y' THEN g.users ELSE NULL END) canonical_users,
       array_agg(CASE WHEN g.canonical = 'N' THEN g.users ELSE NULL END) non_canonical_users
FROM groups g
GROUP BY g.id;
```

it returns `,Larry,Phil` instead of just `Larry,Phil` (in my 9.1.2, it shows `NULL,Larry,Phil`).

Instead, if I use `string_agg()`, it shows me only the names (without empty commas or nulls).

The problem is that I have `Postgres 8.4` installed on the server, and `string_agg()` doesn't work there. **Is there any way to make array_agg work similar to string_agg() ?**

Comment: See this PostgreSQL mailing list thread on much this topic: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/array-agg-NULL-Handling-td2798942.html

Comment: There are two solutions in that thread. One is to create a function and the other (just suggested not shown) is the one I answered.

Comment: @Clodoaldo - all the rows will have canonical in ('y','n')... so the where clause seems to be redundant. The problem is that inside a grouping, if the the value of the canonical field is 'Y', and we are collecting 'N's, then a null be collected too..

Comment: @Daud That mailing list thread mainly explains that there *isn't* a really nice, simple solution and that you have to filter the elements going into `array_agg` for null if you don't want nulls. It's providing background and context, not an answer.

Comment: I'm wondering if I should put together a patch for a null-ignoring `array_agg` variant, since it's so ugly to manually ignore nulls.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
select
    id,
    (select array_agg(a) from unnest(canonical_users) a where a is not null) canonical_users,
    (select array_agg(a) from unnest(non_canonical_users) a where a is not null) non_canonical_users
from (
    SELECT g.id,
           array_agg(CASE WHEN g.canonical = 'Y' THEN g.users ELSE NULL END) canonical_users,
           array_agg(CASE WHEN g.canonical = 'N' THEN g.users ELSE NULL END) non_canonical_users
    FROM groups g
    GROUP BY g.id
) s
```

Or, simpler and may be cheaper, using `array_to_string` which eliminates nulls:

```
SELECT
    g.id,
    array_to_string(
        array_agg(CASE WHEN g.canonical = 'Y' THEN g.users ELSE NULL END)
        , ','
    ) canonical_users,
    array_to_string(
        array_agg(CASE WHEN g.canonical = 'N' THEN g.users ELSE NULL END)
        , ','
    ) non_canonical_users
FROM groups g
GROUP BY g.id
```

Comment: Thanks. But if the main query (s) returns a 1000 rows, then the 2 subqueries (using unnest) will run once for each row.. Will it be better to tolerate NULLs than executing 2000 extra select queries ?

Comment: @Daud New version which could be cheaper. Take the explain output of both to be sure.

Comment: @Clodoaldo If you're using `array_to_string(array_agg(...))` you might as well use `string_agg`.

Comment: @Craig The problem in the question is 8.4

Answer (score 389):

With postgresql-9.3 one can do this;

```
SELECT g.id,
   array_remove(array_agg(CASE WHEN g.canonical = 'Y' THEN g.users ELSE NULL END), NULL) canonical_users,
   array_remove(array_agg(CASE WHEN g.canonical = 'N' THEN g.users ELSE NULL END), NULL) non_canonical_users
FROM groups g 
GROUP BY g.id;
```

**Update**: with postgresql-9.4;

```
SELECT g.id,
   array_agg(g.users) FILTER (WHERE g.canonical = 'Y') canonical_users,
   array_agg(g.users) FILTER (WHERE g.canonical = 'N') non_canonical_users
FROM groups g 
GROUP BY g.id;
```

**Update (2022-02-19)**: also with postgresql-9.4;

This results in an empty array when all values in an array are null instead of returning null;

```
SELECT g.id,
  coalesce( array_agg(g.users) FILTER (WHERE g.canonical = 'Y'), '{}' ) canonical_users,
  coalesce( array_agg(g.users) FILTER (WHERE g.canonical = 'N'), '{}' ) non_canonical_users
FROM groups g 
GROUP BY g.id;
```

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, for other situations you can do something like `array_agg(col_to_aggregate) FILTER (WHERE col_to_aggregate IS NOT NULL)` if you just want to apply the filter directly to that col.

Answer (score 63):

If you are looking for a **modern answer to the general question of how to remove a NULL from an array**, it is:

```
array_remove(your_array, NULL)
```

I was specifically curious about performance and wanted to compare this to the best possible alternative:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION strip_nulls(
    IN array_in ANYARRAY
)
RETURNS anyarray AS
'
SELECT
    array_agg(a)
FROM unnest(array_in) a
WHERE
    a IS NOT NULL
;
'
LANGUAGE sql
;
```

Doing a pgbench test proved (with high confidence) that **array_remove() is a little more than twice as fast**. I did my test on double precision numbers with a variety of array sizes (10, 100 and 1000 elements) and random NULLs in between.

---

It's also worth noting that this can be used to remove blanks ('' != NULL). But the second parameter accepts `anyelement`, and since it is  most likely they you'd be indicating a blank with a string literal, make sure to cast it to the form you want, usually a non-array.

For example:

`select array_remove(array['abc', ''], ''::text);`

If you try:

`select array_remove(array['abc', ''], '');`

it will assume that the '' is TEXT[] (array) and will throw this error:

> ERROR: malformed array literal: ""

Comment: @VivekSinha what version of postgres are you using? I just tested your query and it resulted in "{1,2,3}" for me. I am using 12.1.

Comment: Ah, I see @alexi-theodore what's happening at my end. I was using a custom+modified postgres driver. When I query directly in console, I can see the right output! Sorry about the confusion. Deleted prior comment and upvoted answer!

Comment: Probably it is helpful to note that array_remove is supported since 9.3

Answer (score 15):

In solving the general question of removing nulls from array aggregates there are two main ways of attacking the problem: either doing array_agg(unnest(array_agg(x)) or creating a custom aggregate.

The first is of the form shown [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13123302/299031):

```
SELECT 
    array_agg(u) 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        unnest(
            array_agg(v)
        ) as u 
    FROM 
        x
    ) un
WHERE 
    u IS NOT NULL;
```

The second:

```
/*
With reference to
http://ejrh.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/denormalisation-aggregate-function-for-postgresql/
*/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_array_agg_notnull (
    a anyarray
    , b anyelement
) RETURNS ANYARRAY
AS $$
BEGIN

    IF b IS NOT NULL THEN
        a := array_append(a, b);
    END IF;

    RETURN a;

END;
$$ IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_notnull(ANYELEMENT) (
    SFUNC = fn_array_agg_notnull,
    STYPE = ANYARRAY,
    INITCOND = '{}'
);
```

Calling the second is (naturally) a little nicer looking than the first:

> select array_agg_notnull(v) from x;

Answer (score 9):

I am adding this even though this this thread is quite old, but I ran into this neat trick that works quite well on small arrays. It runs on Postgres 8.4+ without additional libraries or functions.

```
string_to_array(array_to_string(array_agg(my_column)))::int[]
```

The `array_to_string()` method actually gets rid of the nulls.

Answer (score 7):

You should wrap your `array_agg` with [array_remove](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql_array_remove-function.php).

```
SELECT g.id,
       array_remove(array_agg(CASE WHEN g.canonical = 'Y' THEN g.users ELSE NULL END), NULL) canonical_users,
       array_remove(array_agg(CASE WHEN g.canonical = 'N' THEN g.users ELSE NULL END), NULL) non_canonical_users
FROM groups g
GROUP BY g.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

As has been suggested in the comments you can write a function to replace nulls in an array, however as also pointed out in the thread linked to in the comments, this kind of defeats the efficiency of the aggregate function if you have to create an aggregate, split it then aggregate it again.

I think keeping nulls in the array is just a (perhaps unwanted) feature of Array_Agg. You could use subqueries to avoid this:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(y.ID, n.ID) ID,
        y.Users,
        n.Users
FROM    (   SELECT  g.ID, ARRAY_AGG(g.Users) AS Users
            FROM    Groups g
            WHERE   g.Canonical = 'Y'
            GROUP BY g.ID
        ) y
        FULL JOIN 
        (   SELECT  g.ID, ARRAY_AGG(g.Users) AS Users
            FROM    Groups g
            WHERE   g.Canonical = 'N'
            GROUP BY g.ID
        ) n
            ON n.ID = y.ID
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7f0e9/3)**

Comment: Thanks. But I needed 'case' to handle rows within a given grouping, and subqueries would be inefficient there

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, just first of all create a new **- (minus)** operator for **text[]**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION diff_elements_text
    (
        text[], text[] 
    )
RETURNS text[] as 
$$
    SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT new_arr.elem)
    FROM
        unnest($1) as new_arr(elem)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        unnest($2) as old_arr(elem)
        ON new_arr.elem = old_arr.elem
    WHERE old_arr.elem IS NULL
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OPERATOR - (
    PROCEDURE = diff_elements_text,
    leftarg = text[],
    rightarg = text[]
);
```

And simply subtract the array[null]:

```
select 
    array_agg(x)-array['']
from
    (   select 'Y' x union all
        select null union all
        select 'N' union all
        select '' 
    ) x;
```

That's all:

**{Y, N}**

Comment: `array_agg(x) FILTER (WHERE x is not null)` seems a lot easier: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=92da5321389fa18265aa415072377b98 and you don't really need your own function, you can simply use `array_remove()` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4149f45f6304623720ac51a4cefb918a

Answer (score -1):

I did an `array_except`, the concept is `array_except(x,y)`.

```
array_except(array_agg(x), array_agg(case when x is null then x end))
```