# How to convert [NULL] to NULL in Postgres SQL statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres, I set out to write a SQL statement that would return various fields from one table, along with a column containing an array of tag strings that come from another table.  I've made quite good progress with this code:

```
SELECT p.photo_id, p.name, p.path, array_agg(t.tag) as tags FROM photos p
JOIN users u USING (user_id)
LEFT JOIN photo_tags pt USING (photo_id)
LEFT JOIN tags t USING (tag_id)
WHERE u.user_id = 'some_uuid'
GROUP BY p.photo_id, p.name, p.path
ORDER BY date(p.date_created) DESC, p.date_created ASC
```

Everything is working exactly like I intended except for one thing: If a given photo has no tags attached to it then this is being returned: `[NULL]`

I would prefer to return just `NULL` rather than *null in an array*.  I've tried several things, including using `coalesce` and `ifnull` but couldn't fix things precisely the way I want.

Not the end of the world if an array with `NULL` is returned by the endpoint but if you know a way to return just `NULL` instead, I would appreciate learning how to do this.

Comment: You could try `array_remove` like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122912/how-to-exclude-null-values-in-array-agg-like-in-string-agg-using-postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter out nulls during the join process.
If none is returned, you should get a `NULL` instead of `[NULL]`

```
SELECT array_agg(t.tag) filter (where t.tag is not null) as tags
FROM ...
```

Comment: Simple but completely solved it!  Thank you.

Btw the last line in my query - `ORDER BY date(m.date_created) DESC, m.date_created ASC` is a technique I also learned here on StackOverflow.  It groups photos in decreasing chronological order but then within each group (aka day) the photos are sorted in increasing order.  Very much appreciate you all!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a subquery in your case:

```
SELECT p.photo_id, p.name, p.path, agg_tags as tags
FROM photos p
JOIN users u USING (user_id)
LEFT JOIN photo_tags pt USING (photo_id)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tag_id, array_agg(tag) AS agg_tags
    FROM tags
    GROUP BY tag_id
) t USING (tag_id)
WHERE u.user_id = 'some_uuid'
ORDER BY date(p.date_created) DESC, p.date_created ASC
```

You did not post many information about your schema, table size and so on but a `LATERAL` join could be an option to add on the above syntax.